# I can't drag'n'drop UI-Elements from the Scene-hierarchy into a public field (Unity 5)

Tags: unity, gui, objects, hud

I just watched this Video https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-health and tried to drag'n'drop the UI-Elements on the matching script, just like they did. But this is not working for me. If I hover the public field Unity shows up an error icon and I can't drop it there. If I set this UI-Element as prefab I can place it there, but it does not update the Element which is in the Scene when the Code is live. The Elements just gets an update after each restart. Can anybody explain to me why I cannot drag'n'drop my Object from the hierarchy to the public field?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: pics please....

Comment: Added, the mouse icon is not in the screenshot, but it shows an error icon if I hover the public field

Comment: looks like your trying to add a gameobject to an Item field. You should drag your image file from the project view

Comment: So how can I make it to a GUI image? I mean to I get something wrong? Because they do it just like I try to do in the video. At around 9:15 he starts to drag'n'drop the objects into the script. And yes I saw it now in the video, it is a game object, but why is this working for him but not for me?

Comment: And how should I do this with the Slider? I mean nothing works here, it's not just the image

Comment: u use unity 4.6?

Comment: I use Unity 5 at this moment

Comment: I see that tutorial was based on unity 4.6. Maybe there is a chance of portability bug onto unity 5? have you tried to build again your project following tutorial instructions in order to avoid mistakes?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but I think this bug would be pretty obvious for others and I can't find other threads for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a regular game object, create a UI Image ( New >> UI >> Image/slider/etc.).

The new Unity UI system has specifics that aren't available to normal game objects, so when you make them public they need an exact type to be dragged onto them.

This has been my experience at least, hope it helps.

Comment: that is not a regular gameobject. It is a canvas I guess

Comment: Yeah it is just a Canvas with Child Element Image or Slider or whatever you want

Comment: In my code its working. I have using UnityEngine.UI; then in the class it is just a public Image imageName; and is allowing me to drag and drop.

Comment: Are you using Unity 5?

Comment: Yes, but my project was originally made in 4.6. It works in both.